# escape period in JSON substitution to override logging namespace

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have the following structure in my *appsettings.json* and I want to override the value of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` during my release pipeline.

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Override": {
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I put `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override.System.Net.Http.HttpClient` in my Library but the value **didn't** get transformed during the deployment.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-notes:%7E:text=If%20a%20variable%20name%20includes%20periods) about periods but I'm thinking is situation is combination of the two.  `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override` is the hierarchy but `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` is the property.  It doesn't appear to be trying all permutations.

[image: period documetation screenshot]

*Note:* the pipeline is built in the [classic one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 0):

I tested the above JSON variable substitution. It worked fine for me. As it is described in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-notes). The variable `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override.System.Net.Http.HttpClient`  you defined in the library should work as well.

> If a variable name includes periods ("."), the transformation will attempt to locate the item within the JSON hierarchy. as well as `"first.second.third" : "value".`

I could think of below possible reasons that it didn't work for you.

1, The variable `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override.System.Net.Http.HttpClient` you defined in the release pipeline was assigned a wrong `stage Scope`. So that it is not available in the deployment stage.

Please make sure the variable `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override.System.Net.Http.HttpClient` was assigned to `Release Scope` or the correct `stage Scope`

[image]

If the variable `Serilog.MinimumLevel.Override.System.Net.Http.HttpClient` is defined in a `Variables Group` in the Library. Please make sure the Variable Group is linked to the release pipeline and assigned to the correct `Scope`

[image]

2, You didn't specify the appsettings.json file to substitute the variable values in the `JSON variable substitution` section of your web deployment task. Or the JSON file path you defined cannot be found.

You can define `**/appsettings.json` in the `JSON variable substitution` section or a more detailed file path. See below:

[image]

To troubleshoot why the substitution didn't work. You can check the deployment task log to see if the substitution is executed. See below:

[image]